# Perl PL_unitcheckav and .so compiled using Perlbrew

Tags: perl, debugging, openssl, rebuild

I need to build the same set of shared objects (the OpenSSL support) for many platform and Perl version (4x4). Install works well with Perlbrew and I can install various packages with cpan on the different version I'v created. The problem is that they all fail with a PL_unitcheckav not found in DynLoader.pm

I've found lots of similar issues, but no solutione so far. Is this a debug symbol? It only fails when I add (cpan) a package from my brew install and then try to tun it on other system. It works fine when compile "natively" using my local Perl

Comment: I'm not sure what the `PL_unitcheckav` symbol is for, but `UNITCHECK` is a compilation phase, like the `BEGIN` and `INIT` blocks.

Comment: Hard to tell without even the error message, but it sounds like you compiled the module using one build of Perl, but are trying to load it with another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer. As @ikegami said, I was compiling w/o --multi, --64int and --thread and running it on a version with all these flags compiled (version  number was correct). The "multi" option was really the problem